# I want to find the pole associated with this circuit design

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

[image]

the result of the pole location is given as 1/(R(C1 series with C2)) ie 1/R(c1||C2). I am unable to derive it, can anyone help me to derive the transfer function to obtain the pole associated the circuit shown in the picture.

Comment: Is the source on the left a current source?  You've drawn it as a voltage source, and if it were a voltage source Vout = Vin, the transfer function is unity.

Comment: Wrongly drawn, it should be current source, as the impedances are in parallel

Comment: OK, so the output voltage is the input voltage times the impedance of (C1+R) in parallel with the impedance of C2.  Can you write that out and see what you get?

Answer (score 1):

KCL for the node is

$$
\begin{align}
i_{in} ={}& i_1 + i_2\\
={}& \frac{v_o}{R + 1/sC_1} + \frac{v_o}{1/sC_2}\\
={}& v_o (\frac{1}{R + 1/sC_1} + \frac{1}{1/sC_2})\\
={}& v_o \left(\frac{R + 1/sC_1 + 1/sC_2}{(R + 1/sC_1)(1/sC_2)}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

Re arrange this equation to find \$\frac{v_o}{i_{in}}\$. The last line of the above equation set gives a clue to why the pole location is dependent on series or parallel combination of the elements.

Even though the circuit contains *two* energy storing elements, there is only one pole. To see why, think of the case where the input is fixed as 0 (figure below). Then we can see that the three elements \$R,\ C_1,\ C_2\$ are in *series* and there is effectively only one capacitance which is the series combination of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$. <sub>Note that this type of simplification may not be applicable if this was part of a bigger circuit and some other currents were entering or exiting this circuit.</sub>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuCYkom.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks this is used as compensator in design of PLL, so only asked it

Comment: What type of circuit is connected to Vo? If that impedance is low enough, then it may affect the pole calculation.

Comment: its PLL design where output is required to be connected to a VCO as control source. Additional poles added to reduce forward feedthrough

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint is always the have power point or -3 dB.

since the cap dissipates no power at DC , you must inject AC voltage +R or current to get where two strings to have the same impedance seen by source to share power 50%. Using 2R’s and 2C’s where 2nd R source is TBD.  since power is I^2R all you need is impedance ratios to match after you figure out the 2 strings.

Comment: unable to get you, my circuit is used as compensator in design of PLL

Comment: How did you fail to incl that in your question?  so current pump Ic=CdV/dt * d.f.  pump up/dn float

Comment: its was basically to reduce reference feedthrough by adding an additional pole. I even couldn't understand why a capacitor C2 was added instead of R2 and C2 (as a normal low pass filter - in an intuitive sense)

Comment: C2 integrates phase error pump charge pulse while C1R is to further attenuate 2f ripple while giving phase lead compensation at unity gain in an XOR PLL